# pyuic5.bat does not work correctly due to ImportError

Tags: python, anaconda, pyqt5

I am trying to convert a trial.ui file, which is on my desktop, (one that I created from PyQt5 QtDesigner) to trial.py. I [actually found a way](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/convert+ui+to+py) which is `python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x trial.ui -o trial.py` for this case. Previous to this, I tried `C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Library\bin\pyuic5.bat -x trial.ui -o trial.py` however I get an ImportError as shown in the image. [image] I am using Windows 10 and it is Turkish and the last part **Belirtilen modül bulunamadı.** which is in Turkish means **The specified module cannot be found.** How can I solve this ImportError ? I tried copying a few files related to QtCore in C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5 to Library\bin but it did not work out.

Comment: If the python command works, why do you need to use the .bat file?

Comment: I am just curious about how I can fix that problem. For problems that might pop up later.

Comment: You are probably have two python installations, and the one that `pyuic` uses by default is not the same that is run when calling `python` directly. Try opening that bat file and see to what `python.exe` it refers to and compare it with what `where python` returns.

Comment: I found where the bat file refers to. It is C:/Users/ASUS/anaconda3/python.exe . However I am not sure about how to find the python my cmd refers to when I type python. I tried os.getcwd() for that, but I guess it is unrelated. Because it showed C:/Users/ASUS where there is not a 'python.exe'

Comment: As said, you should be able to use `where python` in the command prompt.

Comment: OK when I changed the bat file according to the output from `where python`, `C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Library\bin\pyuic5.bat -x trial.ui -o trial.py` this code worked as well. Thank you.